# exercise schedule without gym equipments

Tags: workout-routines, shoulders, biceps, chest, triceps

I am an IT professional, and don't get much time for exercising. I used to go to the gym, but now I dont get much time. All I have is just 15 minutes in the morning to exercise.

I don't have any fitness equipment at my place. All I do daily is some stretching and a few push ups in addition to a few pull-ups .But doing push ups regularly has created some space between my chest muscles.

So can anyone suggest me a fitness regime that I can follow over a week so that I can focus on other parts of my body as well like shoulders, biceps, triceps without any gym equipment.  Also, an exercise for my chest other than pushups so that I can reduce the space between my chest muscles?

Comment: You want to do exercises for these muscles in a time span of 15 minutes?

Comment: I want a schedule that I can follow over a week.. focusing on 1 body part each day

Comment: If you are doing bodyweight exercises and not weight training at an intermediate-advanced level there is no reason to target a body part per day.

Comment: You can do this 15 minute Workout
http://www.fitfabcities.com/2012/01/17/printable-5-4-3-2-1-workout-cardio-and-weights/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it *really* hard to believe that you have a meagre 15 minutes each day to exercise. If that *is* the case, you should take a serious look at moving around your schedule to allow more time, at least half an hour to 40 minutes. Stay up later, prepare meals in advance to reduce time spent cooking, etc.

Before I explain some things that I do without equipment, I'd like to try persuade you into purchasing *one* great piece of equipment that I have used successfully to strengthen myself overall before I started going to a gym - a boxing bag. These are very cheap and in my experience one of the best pieces of equipment you can get to strengthen yourself overall in short sessions. It's also very fun. With a boxing bag, you can break 15 minutes down however you like for interval training. For a beginner, I would suggest 90 second rounds with a 1 minute break. This should give you 6 rounds total. As you advance you could move up to 3 minute rounds with a 30 second break.

I found the boxing bag really worked my back, triceps, biceps, chest, traps and core. It also has a huge impact on your stamina and balance. Depending on your skill level, you can use a variety of punches and stances to further increase the results. For legs, you can unhook the bag and squat or sprint with it.

As for workouts that I do without a bag, here are a few:

- Pushups - chest.
- Wide grip pull ups - back.
- Close grip pushups - triceps.
- Close grip chinups - biceps.
- Handstand press (against a wall) - shoulders.
- Reverse crunches, planks, side planks - core.
- Not sure what to do about legs. Maybe sprints and bodyweight squats?

Comment: thanks for this answer.. will certainly add boxing bag to my routine.. Just needed a quick suggestion.. how should I start working out with a boxing bag, i.e is there some standard way? because last time I tried it I ended up paining my knuckles for over a week.. :P

Comment: @MitakshGupta Fortunately you can get a pair of gloves along with the bag. I suggest grappling gloves as my personal favourite. They offer plenty protection and mobility.

Comment: +1, Preparing meals in general (especially in advance) is *largely* underrated.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the book "Never Gymless" for someone in your situation, imo it is the resource for training without equipment. It has 100s of equipment free exercises for building all aspects of fitness including strength. Some of the exercises are listed below.

Strength Exercises:
Pushups, Diamond Pushups, Clapping Pushups, One handed Pushups, Pike Presses, Hand Stand Pushups, Calf Raises, Squats, One legged squats, Squat jumps, Pullups, Muscle ups.

Core Exercises:
Planks, L-sits, chinnies, ab wheel roll out (I know it's equipment but very cheap), dragon flag raises.

Conditioning Exercises:
Running, Skipping, Burpees

Program creation based on your goals is also covered in the book and a very important part of training. Anyone can exercise but the difference between training and exercise is having a specific goal and tailoring your exercise routine to attain that goal.

Comment: This sounds like a suggestion and a comment. Is it possible to answer with few exercises in the book that are relevant to the question?

Comment: Sure, I'll had some stuff in.